# New Nvidia 515 non-proprietary update breaks Gnome3 22.04 and others

Tags: nvidia

The most recent update for Nvidia drivers for Ubuntu has broken my display.

On my 22.04 Gnome3 display, I had to fallback to X.org drivers to get a working display.  None of the Nvidia options (515 proprietary-tested, the new non-proprietary 515, the 510, nothing).

I have a 'playground' SSD where I try out new Ubuntu distros.  This update also broke the Ubuntu Unity install.

** Update **

Just loaded and installed the newest 520 Driver package.  Was hoping that would fix the issue.

Nope.  Still crashes to low-res, single monitor.  Had to fallback to X.org to get a working display

Comment: this Q&A site is for questions about Ubuntu, not bug reports. The users of this site are not developers, they are regular users who are willing to help you fix issues. If you have a bug report, please see [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) If you have a question about an issue that needs fixing, we will need a lot more information about your hardware and such, and more information about what's going wrong (logs, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Update, again

I managed to get the 515 proprietary drivers to work in both 22.04 and 20.04.

When I tried the 520 drivers, it did not work.

On boot, I noticed that gpu-manager.service crashed, and could not find/detect/deal with my 3060.

At least 515 is working.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but a comment on it.

Answer (score -1):

I had issues with Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I fixed my black screen issues by running these commands in recovery mode:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge '*nvidia*'
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-520
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

The first line should uninstall every nvidia driver package, including those that might be damaged.
The second one installs the latest nvidia-driver I could find.
I had issue with the "open" version, so you may want to try 520 as well.
If not, after the purge, try `nvidia-driver-520-open` and see what happens.